# WiFi connection intermittently dropping on Dell Laptop

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a strange problem with my wireless internet...
It seems to "drop" every 5 / 10 mins or so.

Opening CMD prompt and doing ipconfig /release followed by ipconfig /renew fixes the problem.

The plot thickens however:

It only seems to "drop" for browsers / loading pages.

For example- it won't load pages... however, it will continue to download files, or, if I'm connected to Facebook, Facebook Chat will still send / receive messages!

I've tried updating the WiFi card drivers etc...

Comment: Do computers wired to your router get the same issue? do you see the same issue if you bypass the router altogether? its possible you have a DNS issue, somewhat intermittent, might be ISP related.

Answer (score 1):

Is there possibly an MTU issue on the router.  This will mainifest as pages not loading while FTP and otehr protocols work fine.

Have alook at [MTU Ping test](http://help.expedient.com/broadband/mtu_ping_test.shtml). It will get you started.

Comment: wow, thanks for your near immediate answer! How can I resolve this..? The router is a D-Link DIR 655

Comment: See edits in answer